# tkdiff installation problem on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, software-installation

I am just trying to install `tkdiff` on my centos 7.
For installation I am running below cmd:

```
sudo yum install tkdiff
```

but I am getting error message:

```
   No package tkdiff available.
   Error: Nothing to do
```

Could someone please help to install `tkdiff`.
I am beginner in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkdiff` is included in the [tkcvs](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/tkcvs-8.2.3-1.el7.noarch.rpm.html) package.

You can install it with

```
sudo yum install tkcvs
```

Comment: is it the same as tkdiff?

Comment: The package contains `tkdiff` (yes, it is the real `tkdiff`) _and_ `tkcvs` which is a package to maintain CVS and subversion repositories. Quote: "TkCVS is a Tcl/Tk-based graphical interface to the CVS and Subversion
configuration management systems. It will also help with RCS. TkDiff
is included for browsing and merging your changes."

Comment: currently I am trying to compare two files via below cmd:
  tkdiff file1 file2
and geting error:
  bash: /usr/local/bin/tkdiff: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you install `tkcvs` with `sudo yum install tkcvs`? According to the link it should have been installed to `/usr/bin/tkdiff`. What does `which tkdiff` show you?

Comment: ok now it works, the problem was that I have changed my terminal to tcsh and after changing it back to bash everything works. thanks a lot!